# Non-repeatable affinity for pthreads

Tags: multithreading, pthreads, profiling, affinity

I am trying to measure the time it takes for a thread from creation to actually start.

Using `POSIX thread` on a Debian 6.0 machine with 32-cores (no hyper-threading) and calling `pthread_attr_setaffinity_np` function to set the affinity.

In a loop, I am creating the threads, waiting for them to finish, repeatedly.

So, my code looks like the following (thread 0 is running this).

```
for (ni=0; ni<n; ni++)
   {
      pthread_t *thrds;
      pthread_attr_t attr;
      cpu_set_t cpuset;
      ths = 1; // thread starts from 1

      thrds = malloc(sizeof(pthread_t)*nt); // thrds[0] not used
      assert(!pthread_attr_init(&attr));
      for (i=ths; i<nt; i++)
      {
         pthread_attr_setscope(&attr, PTHREAD_SCOPE_SYSTEM);
         CPU_ZERO(&cpuset);
         CPU_SET(i, &cpuset); // setting i as the affinity for thread i
         assert(!pthread_attr_setaffinity_np(&attr,
                  sizeof(cpu_set_t), &cpuset));
         assert(!pthread_create(thrds+i, &attr, DoWork, i));
      }
      pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);

      DoWork(0);

      for (i=ths; i<nt; i++)
      {
         pthread_join(thrds[i], NULL);
      }
      if (thrds) free(thrds);
   }
```

Inside the thread function, I am calling `sched_getcpu()` to verify that the affinity is working. The problem is, this verification only passes the first iteration of `i-loop`. For the second iteration, `thrd[1]` gets the affinity of `nt-1` (instead of 1) and so on.

Can anyone please explain why? And/or how to fix it?

NOTE: I found a workaround that if I put the master thread to sleep for 1 second after the join finishes at each iteration, the affinity works correctly. But this sleep duration could different on other machines. So still need a real fix for the issue.

Comment: `pthread_setaffinity_np` takes several arguments, such as the thread ID. You can't set the affinity of a thread before `pthread_create`, because it doesn't exist; you need its ID.

Comment: My mistake. The function I am using actually is pthread_attr_setaffinity_np . Hope this clears up the confusion.

Comment: You should post your actual code. The sample has issues, like missing function arguments. The two inner loops don't use exactly the same bounds, and seem to be wrongly using `thrd[i]`: the outer loop variable rather than the inner one, `thrd[t]`.

Comment: Sorry for the typos. Just wanted to keep it simple. Now it should be correct.